# Security Update Breaks Old Games

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

There was recently [a security update by Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3086255) implemented for Windows 7, 8 and 10 that [completely destroys native compatibility](http://www.howtogeek.com/230773/how-to-play-pc-games-that-require-safedisc-or-securom-drm-on-windows-10-8.1-8-7-and-vista/) with a [very large handful of old games](http://forum.daemon-tools.cc/gamedb.php?letter=all), namely anything with SafeDisc or SecuROM write protection built in.  I spent quite a bit of time trying to figure out why my eBay-bought version of American McGee's Alice didn't run under any compatibility settings because no one seemed to have the same issue as I did.  Obviously I wasn't aware of the security patch, or even that this game released in 2000 would have copy protection that could be broken by a Windows update.  I was able to fix it after a LOT of searching (and I'm pretty tech-savvy), and even then I think I was pretty lucky to have stumbled upon the solution.

Needless to say, this silent patch is going to confuse the heck out of a lot of gamers when their old CD-based games just don't launch and there's seemingly no answer to why.  So my question is:  should I post a question and answer on this site detailing what is wrong and how to fix it?  Should I include an abbreviated list of popular affected games?  As it affects a substantial number of games, what should I title the question, and what should I tag it with?

**EDIT:**  I have now posted [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/246786/96435).  Thanks for your help!

Comment: [tag:backwards-compatibility] would be an appropriate tag for this. Personally I'm not sold on the idea of including even a partial list - I'd rather you included a short description on how to identify if a game is affected or not

Comment: @JonK the problem description would go in the question, but the game list could go in the answer.  It might make it easier to find from a Google search

Comment: Someone broke securom? The tears, I can't find them.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Yes**, such a solution would benefit many people having the same problem and would be most welcome here :).

> Should I include an abbreviated list of popular affected games?

List the games that you have personally dealt with and confirmed working specifically, with links off to a more complete list of affected titles elsewhere if available. It's sufficient enough to provide the generalised solution with the right references and imply that most affected games can also be fixed by this.

> What should I title the question, and what should I tag it with?

If there a specific error message that points to this issue, then I would suggest titling your question with something like *"Why do older games give "<error>" message?"*. If there is not a specific error message, then perhaps something like *"Why are older games crashing after Windows Update on Windows 7, 8 and 10?"*.

As for tags, [backwards-compatibility](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/backwards-compatibility), [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) and [windows](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows) would seem to fit pretty well.